# Heredoc with tmpfile

Tags: c, io-redirection, heredoc

I am writing my version of minishell and trying to implement heredoc (`<<`) in C. I decided to use tmpfile - first I write data from `stdin` to tmpfile until I reach a delimiter, then I change program's stdin to the `fd` of the tmpfile with `dup2` and, then, try to execute `cat` command with `execve`.

I tried to simplify the program and include all relevant functions below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    t_shell     shell;
    ft_parse_envs_to_lst(&envs, env); // transform env to linked list
    shell.tmpfile = "path to tmpfile";
    while (1)
    {
        char *buf = readline("bash: ");
        add_history(buf);
        shell.std_in = dup(0);
        shell.std_out = dup(1);
        shell.f_in = dup(0);
        shell.f_out = dup(1);
        /* Token is represented by linked list. "cat << eof" translates into "cat" -> ">>" -> "eof",
        with token pointing to "cat" */
        t_token *token = parse_buffer(buf); // parse_buffer will return pointer to the first token
        ft_execute_token(shell, token, env);
        free(buf);
    }
}

void    ft_execute_token(t_shell *shell, t_token *token, t_envs_lst *env)
{
    process_next_cmd(shell, token, env);
    close(shell->f_in);
    close(shell->f_out);
    dup2(shell->std_in, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(shell->std_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(shell->std_in);
    close(shell->std_out);
}

void    process_next_cmd(t_shell *shell, t_token *token, t_envs_lst *env)
{
    t_token *prev = ft_get_prev_token(token); // get prev separator (for example, <<) or NULL
    t_token *next = ft_get_next_token(token); // get next separator (for example, <<) or NULL
    if (prev && (prev->type == DOBINP)) // "<<" will be marked as DOBINP
        ft_handle_dobinp(shell, token);
    if (next)
        process_next_cmd(shell, next->next, env); // recursively go to the next command
    if (!prev) // won't run any command on the part after "<<"" but will run "cat" 
    {
        ft_execute_cmd(token, env); // just execve on child process (created with fork), whilst parent is waiting for child
        if (next && next->type == DOBINP) // delete tmpfile
        {
            char **argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
            argv[0] = "/bin/rm";
            argv[1] = shell->tmpfile;
            argv[2] = NULL;
            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
                execve("/bin/rm", argv, NULL);
        }
    }
}

void    handle_dobinp(t_shell *shell, t_token *token)
{
    int     rd;
    int     fd;
    int     buf_size;
    char    *buf;

    fd = open(shell->tmpfile, O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0777);
    buf_size = strlen(token->str);
    buf = malloc(buf_size + 1);
    printf("program: Start\n");
    rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buf_size);
    while (rd > 0)
    {
        buf[rd] = '\0';
        printf("program: Looping (read %s)", buf);
        if (strncmp(buf, token->str, buf_size + 1) == 0)
            break ;
        write(fd, buf, rd);
        rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buf_size);
    }
    free(buf);
    close(fd);
    shell->f_in = open(shell->tmpfile, O_RDONLY, 0777);
    dup2(shell->f_in, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(shell->f_in);
}
```

I want to execute `cat << eof` command. Everything works fine but I face with the problem of repeated output (during testing) in `handle_dobinp` function. Also one more iteration occurs in `while` cycle in `main` with empty input (i.e. program executed empty command).

There is only one process running, so I am not sure what is the cause of this behaviour?

**Update:** I updated program's output according to [Edwin Buck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70238990/12326837) comment.

```
bash$ cat << eof
program: Start
foo
program: Looping (read foo
)
bar
program: Looping (read bar)
program: Looping (read 
)
eof
program: Looping (read eof)
foo
bar
bash$ 
bash$
```

Comment: don't repeat yourself, do `while((rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buf_size)) > 0)` or `while(rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buf_size), rd > 0)`

Comment: @KamilCuk agree, but I cannot use assignment in control structure according to the school's coding guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve your logging.  I imagine your output is correct, but looking like

```
bash$ cat << eof
program: Start
foo
program: Looping (read "foo")
program: Looping (read "\n")
bar
program: Looping (read "bar")
program: Looping (read "\n")
eof
program: Looping (read "eof")
program: foo
program: bar
bash$ 
bash$
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Can you pls suggest any ideas of how to avoid executing empty command in the end?

Comment: My guess is that your "empty command" is the last "\n" at the end of the `eof` string.  It is executing the same way as if you typed <ENTER>.  Instead, I would make sure that when you read, you read up (and including) the newline '\n' before starting the command.  That way you only get one input "eof\n" instead of two "eof", "\n"

Comment: I wrote custom get_next_line (which reads from stdin up and including "\n") and it worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: @alexnik42 Glad to hear it.  Have fun with your new shell!